# Delete local data generated by Google App Engine's dev_appserver.py

Tags: python, google-app-engine, dev-appserver

I run my application locally using `dev_appserver.py`

using the following command

`dev_appserver.py mydir --port=xxxx`

Is there a way to delete all the `local data` generated by app engine server.

Currently, I go to localhost:8000/datastore, and delete entity groups manually.

1. IS there a way to automate it
2. Where does dev_appserver.py write local data to? (File or directory? may be in can delete that)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is!

`dev_appserver.py` accepts some arguments that clears things before it starts up.  Two arguments that I use consistently are:

```
dev_appserver.py --clear_datastore=true --clear_search_indexes=true ...
```

`dev_appserver.py --help` can probably give you more information about other things that you may want to clear -- But this always gets everything I need it too.

Comment: Note `dev_appserver.py` must be worked on folder containing `app.ymal`